# Add string categories for y-axis in highcharts when series data is of object array type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I need to display string labels for y-Axis, with datetime as the x-Axis. My series data looks like -

```
data: [{"y":1.0,"x":1487548800000},{"y":1.0,"x":1487894400000},{"y":1.0,"x":1494547200000}]
```

The categories I am providing looks like - ["A","B","C","D"] where A can be mapped to 1.0, B to 2.0, C to 3.0, and so on. 
my yAxis config is:

```
yAxis: {
       categories: scope.defaultTag.yAxis!== undefined ? scope.defaultTag.yAxis.categories : null,
        labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                           return this.value;
                 }
        }
}
```

What can I do to make the string labels appear instead of the numbers? Also, the graph is generic, and I can't hard code the categories.

Comment: how you are providing `["A","B","C","D"]` as categories. this data is not avalilable with `data`

Comment: I am passing it in a variable as shown above - scope.defaulttag.yAxis.categories

Comment: it should work , can you add plunker example to show problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3pLz0e2/12/
It's showing the labels, but 1.0 is being mapped to B instead of A. How would I map the number to string?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxc6op9r/ check this

Comment: Sorry, this is for highstocks. Categories isn't a property for highstocks. Any work around for that?

Comment: Create a map for the labels. Use axis values as keys for the map - http://jsfiddle.net/fxc6op9r/1/